# Compile with Clang and use GETTEXT

Tags: c, clang, gettext, automake

I have a automake enabled project which I would like to compile with clang. I have added a configure option to enable clang:

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE([clang],
     [AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-clang],[use clang instead of gcc as C compiler.])])

#Use C99 compilation mode
if test "x$enable_clang" = "xyes"; then
    # clang uses c99 mode by default, so we just set CC to clang and we are done
    CC="clang";
else
    # We do not need to set CC as the default is gcc, but we need to set it to
    # use C99 compilation mode
    CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -std=c99";
fi
```

Further up in the file I have also the following two macros, to enable gettext functionality:

```
AM_GNU_GETTEXT_VERSION([0.18.1])
AM_GNU_GETTEXT([external])
```

If these two macros are present then configure ignores that the `CC` variable is set to `clang` and falls back to `gcc`. I have to comment out the gettext macros and then clang is used.

Obviously there is some problem with GETTEXT and clang. Am I using the wrong macro, or is clang not able to use the gnu gettext library? How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to set `CC` to `clang` *before* you check for libraries (like gettext)?

Comment: There's really no need to do this.  `./configure CC=clang CFLAGS="-std=c99 ..." ...` should work without the first section of code (`AC_ARG_ENABLE`, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to set `CC` to `clang` *before* you check for libraries (like gettext)? – Some programmer dude

Nice that worked. – lanoxx